# Private inheritance along class hierarchy, why friend is needed all along the hierarchy

Tags: c++, friend

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
    friend class C;
    int a{42};
};

class B: private A{
    friend class C;
};

class C: private B {
public:
    void print() {std::cout << a << '\n';}
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.print();
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1372858/3093378), the member variable `A::a` is "present" in all classes, but its visibility differ, i.e. is not visible in `B` or `C` unless we make `B` or `C` a friend of `A`. My question is why do I need to make `C` a friend of **both** `A` and `B`? I would've though the friend declaration in `A` would suffice. If I remove the `friend class C;` declaration from either `A` or `B`, the code fails to compile.

Comment: The answer that the question links to correctly refers to **access**; this question incorrectly talks about **visibility**. They're two different things. `a` is visible throughout the hierarchy, but it's private in `A`, so without the `friend` declarations it's not accessible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is why do I need to make C a friend of **both** A and B?

Without `B` declaring `C` has a friend, `C` wouldn't *see* `B` as inheriting `A`. Even though `C` would *see* `A::a`, it would not *see* `B::a`.

Indeed:

- `C` inherits `B`, so anything *public* in `B` is accessible from `C`.
- But `B` inherits *privately* from `A`. `C` being a friend of `B` makes `C` *see* this inheritance.
- The access of `A::a` is private, so even though `C` *sees* `A` as its ancestor, it needs to be a friend of `A` to *see* `A::a`.

Comment: Thanks, but still `cout << A::a` in `C` won't work... And `C` inherits privately as well from `B`.

Comment: @vsoftco With only the friendship C<->A, `A::a` can't be accessed from `C`without an instance of `A`. It needs friendship B<->A to know it _is an_ `A` and it contains an `A::a`.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, although I though that even without accessibility levels the compiler knows the "is-a/has-a" relation anyway, but looks like it's not the case. At least that's the impression one gets reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance/1372858#1372858) (even mentioned as  IMPORTANT NOTE).

Comment: I take that back, seems that the compiler knows the is-a/has-a relationship only between child/parent, and not along a hierarchy.

Comment: "The visibility of A::a is private" -- no. The **access** of `A::a` is private. Visibility is not affected by accessibility.

Comment: Thank you @Pete; I think I got mixed up by the verb "see" I use throughout the answer. Fixed.

Comment: It's a subtle distinction, and other languages (I'm looking at you, Java) do it differently. I'm considering writing a question and self-answer about the difference and why it matters.

Comment: @Pete Please do so and link it there.